# What is Mono C# equivalent of Java's -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError="custom shell command"?

Tags: c#, ubuntu, mono

In Java, it is possible to register some sort of system callback to be executed on out of memory error by using -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError option.

Is there such a option in Mono C#?

EDIT: Main purpose of this question is to find a way to determine if third party C# program exited with OutOfMemory exception.

In case of Java I can use -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError="kill -SIGUSR1 parent_pid" mechanism, where parent_pid is pid of process that will fork child in which C# program will be executed.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no equivalent to XX:OnOutOfMemoryError in the Mono or .Net runtimes.

You would need to code OutOfMemory exception handling in your C# code and since you are on Linux, you would also have to determine if the OOM Killer should monitor your app to handle non-managed out of memory conditions.

Comment: You wrongly assumed that I wrote the code. Code is going to be written by students and idea is to limit heap size for certain problems that they will be solving. So, detection that their program broke memory limit is the actual problem.